# Cognex vision pro silent installation

Tags: silent-installer, cognex

How to perform silent installation of Cognex vision pro.   I tried silent switch mentioned in Cognex website its not working.  I also tried to create but setup. iss file but it is also not created. Setup is an InstallShield package.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

It's not vision pro, but may help you. You should start the setup.exe with "-r" switch(record) to create a setup.iss file in the C:\Windows folder. Then you have to copy the answer file to the install directory.

Comment: I already tried to create. iss file but using record switch it was not creating any iss file. I tried other switches also but not working... anyway thank you for taking time to answer my question.  If you have any other information please let me know.